# Cannot passing dynamically created image's ID and alert it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an image dynamically in Jquery and trying to add a control to it When the user clicks the image, I want to popup alert() with the image's id. But I couldnt succeed to show id of the image in the alert box. Please help me display the id of the image in alert box.

here is the code display the alert box

```
function category_follow(search_txt) {
    alert(this.Attr('name'));
}
```

here is the code where I create the image dynamically

```
$.ajax({
url: 'HoverCard_WebService.aspx?q=' + encodeURIComponent(span_text),
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',

beforeSend: function () {
    $(".hovercard").prepend('<p class="loading-text">Yükleniyor...</p>');
},
success: function (data) {
    $(".hovercard").empty();
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        var search_txt = 'TestArif4';
        result += '<div><button class=\'takibe_al\' name=\'test_name\' id=\'btn_test_id\' onClick=category_follow(\'' + value.id + '\')><img id=\'img_category_follow\' src=\'images/hover_card_plus_icon.png\' class=\'hover_cursor_hand\' /></button></div>';
    });
},
```

Comment: I don't believe this.Attr is valid. You may be looking for $(this).attr?

Comment: ...and `this` refers to the DOM Element and not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing with your "result" variable?

```
function category_follow(search_txt) {
    alert(this.Attr('name'));
}
```

`this` refers to the DOM Element and "Attr" should probably be "[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)" if you are using jQuery.

I recommend you to use jQuery to bind your events instead of using the element attribute `onClick`;

```
$(document).on('click', '.takibe_al', function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  alert('Clicked on element with name = ' + $this.attr('name'));
});
```

See [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).